# Search with related word in editText from array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I made an array of address and there are 5 values in it.

```
String address[] = {
    "New York",
    "Sydney",
    "Brisbane",
    "Paris",
    "Milan"
}
```

I wrote a code for event `onClicklistener` in `MapsActivity`. I use this event to search some marker in my maps activity with the title from array value.

```
btncari.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            for(int i=0; i < address.length; i++) {
                if (nama[i].equalsIgnoreCase(editcari.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    marker.remove();
                    myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat[i], lon[i])).title(nama[i])
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_wisata))
                    );
                    CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(lat[i],  lon[i]))
                            .zoom(18)
                            .build();
                    CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);
                    myMap.animateCamera(camUpd3);
                    break;
                } else
                {
                    editcari.setText("Unavailable");
                }
            }}
    });
```

If I want to type some address in `EditText` but the words is not exactly same with real address value, for example if I type on `EditText` only "ari" it will show "Paris", so I don't need to type full address in array value. How to solve this problem?

Comment: use textwatcher instead u won't need to define button , its a easy and fast solution, Text watcher automatically get the text from your edit text and search from the given array list

Comment: What  if there are more than 2 elements containing the input text?

Comment: i only type address in input text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
nama[i].toLowerCase().contains(editcari.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase())
// ^^^^^^^^^^     convert array values to lowercase
// convert input to lower case                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                            
// check array value contains the input
```

or add values in array as lowercase and then use `nama[i].contains`

and one little improvement

```
String input = editcari.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
// take input only once , outside loop
for(int i=0; i < address.length; i++) {
         if (nama[i].toLowerCase().contains(input)) {
```

Comment: is it only ignore lower case and uppercase? i need to type a some word that related to the array values like i type "ari" it will show "paris"

Comment: yes and contains will cover the part where you want to check paris contains ari an it will give you true

Comment: i have another problem which is when i press `search` button directly it will show the first array. i want to show an error warning

Comment: add an `if` before loop `if (!input.isEmpty()) {// your loop code}else{//show error}`

Comment: thanks  for suggestion, now i'm add `if condition` berfore loop like this `if (editsearch.getTtext().toString().isEmpty()) {//my loop code} else {//showerror}` and it's worked